# clean up simple animation jquery code

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate a div up and down, in quick succession, for a limited time. This works in jquery to make it happen, but it is so messy:

```
 $('.wiggle').delay(1800).show(50).animate({
                top: '15'
                              }, 40, function() {
                                 $('.wiggle').animate({
                                 top: '12'
                                 }, 40, function() {
                                    $('.wiggle').animate({
                                    top: '15'
                                    }, 40, function() {
                                        $('.wiggle').animate({
                                        top: '12'
                                        }, 40, function() {
                                            $('.wiggle').animate({
                                            top: '15'
                                            }, 40, function() {
                                                $('.wiggle').animate({
                                                top: '12'
                                                }, 40, function() {
                                                    $('.wiggle').animate({
                                                    top: '15'
                                                    }, 40, function() {
                                                        $('.wiggle').animate({
                                                        top: '12'
                                                        }, 40, function() {
                                                            $('.wiggle').animate({
                                                            top: '15'
                                                            }, 40, function() {
                                                                $('.wiggle').animate({
                                                                top: '12'
                                                                }, 40, function() {
                                                                    $('.wiggle').animate({
                                                                    top: '14'
                                                                    }, 40, function() {
                                                                        $('.wiggle').hide(50)
                                                                     });
                                                                 });
                                                             });
                                                         });
                                                     });
                                                 });
                                             });
                                         });
                                     });
                                 });
                             }); //end wiggle
```

I know it is bad. I'd like to create a unique function to make this happen, but I am lost as to where to start.

Comment: Your poor stack heap..... You're killing it.

Comment: @gbtimmon, That's why she asked the question.

Comment: You could use jqueryUI's effect library to simplfy things: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: Shouldn't this question be at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you decide how long overall you want the effect to run, then encapsulate the actions into a single function that will take care of recursing and stopping:

```
function wiggle(selector, duration_of_wiggle) {
    var wiggle_active = true;
    var target = $(selector);
    setTimeout(function () {
        wiggle_active = false;
        target.hide();
    }, duration_of_wiggle);
    var one_wiggle_down = function () {
        if (!wiggle_active)
            return;
        target.animate({
            top: '15'
        }, 40, one_wiggle_up);
    };    
    var one_wiggle_up = function () {
        if (!wiggle_active)
            return;
        target.animate({
            top: '12'
        }, 40, one_wiggle_down);
    };
    one_wiggle_down();
};

wiggle('.wiggle', 1000);
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/P4H9c/1/

Comment: Oh yeah, this is much better. Perfect

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.wiggle').delay(1800).show(50).wiggle(12);

$.fn.wiggle = function(i) {

    var $elem = $(this);

    if (i > 0) {

        $elem.animate({
            top: i % 2 == 0 ? 15 : 12
        }, 40, function() {

            $elem.wiggle(i--);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think you have to setup a function something like the following (not sure if this does exactly what you want because it is pretty hard to tell with the "mess", but it should give you an idea):

```
function doWiggle($elem, numberOfTimesToWiggle)
{
    $elem.animate({
        top: '15'
    }, 40, function() {
        top: '12'
    }, 40, function() {
        doWiggle($elem, (numberOfTimesToWiggle-1));
    });

}

setTimeout(function() {
    show(5);
    doWiggle($('.wiggle'), 20);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by saving into a var the object selected this give's a better performance

```
var $wiggle = $('.wiggle');

$wiggle.delay(1800).show(50).animate({
            top: '15'
                          }, 40, function() {
                             $wiggle.animate({ //and so on..
```

Second Improve the selector. If the html related with the elements it's alway's the same, let's a `div` you could do this

```
var $wiggle = $('div.wiggle')
```

Third, for what i see in your code you're trying to accomplish a bounce effect or move down and up Wrap the function in a method and do a for something like

```
function bounce(wiggle) {
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
        wiggle.animate({
            top: '12px'
        }, 75);
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        paquete.animate({
            top: '15px'
        }, 75);
    }
    }
  wiggle.hide();
}
```

Then you just called the function

```
var $wiggle = $('.wiggle');

bounce($wiggle);
```

Comment: This doesn't clean up that mess.

Comment: Could I create a .fn that would handle it by getting the css from the div and changing it to "top: +1" or "-1"

Comment: remember check the answer as accepted if my considers my answer as a correct question

Comment: @Petra now, that i'm finish the answer this does the clean